# Script usage for output

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am having 230 directories(*_t) where I need to grep "Unseen Issues" in report.rt file in all directories.
I have tried this :

```
grep -r "Unseen Issues" *_t/A_*/ar.rt
```

I got this where pf_t, pu_t, pv_t, pz_t are directories:

```
pf_t/A_output/ar.rt:Number of Unseen Issues      = 3
pf_t/A_output/ar.rt:adsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )
pf_t/A_output/ar.rt:edsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )
pf_t/A_output/ar.rt:wdsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )
pu_t/A_output/ar.rt:Number of Unseen Issues      = 0
pv_t/A_output/ar.rt:Number of Unseen Issues      = 0
pz_t/A_output/ar.rt:Number of Unseen Issues      = 0
```

But I need the output in this way below:

```
pf_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 3
adsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )
edsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )
wdsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )

pu_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 0

pv_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 0

pz_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 0
```

Can anyone please help me with any small script to get the output as above with using above grep command.

We can use any script can anyone please help me.

Comment: Please specify whether the answer must be `bash` only, or if it can use other utils like `sed`, or `awk`.

Comment: @agc anything we can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using AWK if the intermediate text file `test1.txt` is important.  Otherwise a shell loop is simple:

```
for d in *_t; do
    echo "$d"
    grep -h "Unseen Issues" $d/A_*/ar.rt
    echo ""
done
```

Added a test case and ran the script from command-line:

```
$ find * -type f
pf_t/A_output/ar.rt
pu_t/A_output/ar.rt
pv_t/A_output/ar.rt
pz_t/A_output/ar.rt


$ for d in *_t; do echo "$d"; grep -h "Unseen Issues" $d/A_*/ar.rt; echo ""; done
pf_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 3
adsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )
edsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )
wdsd1p2r                50              Unseen Issues ( 1 )

pu_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 0

pv_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 0

pz_t
Number of Unseen Issues      = 0
```

Comment: `cat $d/A_*/ar.rt | grep "Unseen Issues"` = `grep -h 'Unseen Issues' "$d"/A_*/ar.rt`. See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html.